# how to use redux in react for get data from api

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux

Hello i am just starting to learn redux and am currently having a problem, i have an api i want to get information from and use it in different components i would appreciate if you help me

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import { BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import Reducer from './Reducers';

import App from './App';
import fetchSimcards from './Actions/fetchSimcards';

const middleware = [ thunk ];
middleware.push( createLogger() );

const store = createStore(
Reducer
applyMiddleware(...middleware),
);


import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

store.dispatch(fetchSimcards());

render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>,

document.getElementById('root')
 );

 serviceWorker.unregister();
```

and this is my action file

```
import * as type from '../Constans/ActionTypes';

 export const ReceiveSimcards = Simcards => ({
type: type.RECEIVE_SIMCARDS,
Simcards
});
```

this is my reducer file

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const Simcards = ( state = {}, action ) => {
console.log( state, action );
return state;
};

export default combineReducers({
Simcards
});
```

this is my container file for simcards

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SimcardList from "../Component/SimcardList";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class SimcardContainer extends Component {
render() {
    const Simcards = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <SimcardList title={"Simcards"} />
            <div className="TableNumberItem">{Simcards.SimCardNumber}</div>
            <div className="TableNumberItem">{Simcards.SimCardDescription}</div>
            <div className="TableNumberItem">{Simcards.TeammatePrice}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default connect()(SimcardContainer);
```

and i want show this container in home page

Comment: you already have [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) but I don't see an action that gets the data. You could also use [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch) to dispatch an action in [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), example [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/data-list/blob/master/List/index.js#L35-L39)

Comment: Thanks for your guide but I'm just starting to learn redux and I'm not very professional about it. If you can make a demo for me at https://codesandbox.io/ it is great and I better understand how How to make components, what names to choose for components, and ...

Comment: For a class based thunk example I think [this one](https://appdividend.com/2018/10/03/redux-thunk-tutorial-example/) is a basic example. I prefer using [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) in selecting stuff from state but that is another subject.

Answer (score 0):

With redux, you should call all API and handling logic code in action.
Example with action fetchAPI:

```
   export const fetchAPI = () = async dispatch => {
        let response = null;
        try {
            response = await axios.get('api/...')
            // Example use axios
            dispatch(fetchSuccess(response.data)) 
            // To handle in reducer with redux
        } catch (error) {
            ... Handle error here
        }
    }
    const fetchSuccess = data => ({
        type: FETCH_SUCCESS,
        data: response.data
    })
```

And in your component, you can use connect to get state and action:

```
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import SimcardList from "../Component/SimcardList";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import * as _Actions from '../../action/index'

    class SimcardContainer extends Component {
        componentDidMount(){
            const { fetchAPI } = this.props.actions;
            **fetchAPI();** // Call API here
        }
        render() {
            const { stateReducer} = this.props;
            console.log(stateReducer) 
            // Here, you will see data that you handled in reducer 
            // with action type FETCH_SUCCESS
            // You should remember data that you fetch from API is asynchronous,
            // So you should check like that `data && {do any thing heree}`
            return (
                <div>
                    <SimcardList title={"Simcards"} />
                    <div className="TableNumberItem">{Simcards.SimCardNumber}</div>
                    <div className="TableNumberItem">{Simcards.SimCardDescription}</div>
                    <div className="TableNumberItem">{Simcards.TeammatePrice}</div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        stateReducer: state  
    })
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        actions: bindActionCreators(_Actions, dispatch)
    })
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SimcardContainer)
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I use reducers and containers?

Comment: Thanks for your guide but I'm just starting to learn redux and I'm not very professional about it. If you can make a demo for me at https://codesandbox.io/ it is great and I better understand how How to make components, what names to choose for components, and ...

Comment: Here is my codesandbox that I created when I start study redux. Hope to help you.
Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/xlmyxr8qlz

Comment: Oh no. This example don't have fetchAPI. If you want to fetch API, you write them in export functions in TodoAction at TodoAction.js file